# How to use promises in javascript

Tags: javascript, cordova, typescript, asynchronous, promise

I am making an app for Android in Cordova, with Typescript, and I bundle with Webpack. I don't understand very well how to do asynchronous tasks in Javascript. I saw several tutorials on callbacks and promises, but it's still very confused for me and I don't manage to adapt it to my code. I don't know if my problem comes from my code itself, or from Typescript/Cordova/Webpack.

I created a function `getAllSMS` that return a big object, and takes some time to execute. I know the function works because if I try to print the `allSMS` variable in the inspector's console, it's empty at first and then filled in like 1 second. (I think that behavior of the inspector is quite strange, but it really does that).

I saw I can do asynchronous tasks with promises, but I have some problems to understand how it works. I have seen several tutorials but I still don't understand how to apply it to my code.

Thanks

[EDIT] : Here's my getAllSMS function converted to a promise :

```
public getAllSMS() {
    return new Promise(//return a promise
        (resolve,reject)=>{
            if (SMS) {
                SMS.listSMS(this.filters, function (data) {
                    resolve(data);//added this, resolve promise
                }, function (err) {
                    console.log('error list sms: ' + err);
                    reject(err);//added this reject promise
                });
            }else{
                resolve([]);//added this, resolving to empty array?
            }
        }
    ).then(
        data=>{
            let contacts = {};
                            for (let key in data) {
                                if ((data[key].address).length > 7 && (data[key].address).match("[0-9]+")) {
                                    let date = SMSManager.convertUnixDate(data[key].date); // on converti le format de date de listSMS
                                    if (contacts.hasOwnProperty(data[key].address)) {
                                        Object.defineProperty(contacts[data[key].address], data[key]._id, {
                                            value: {
                                                "body": data[key].body,
                                                "date": date
                                            }
                                        });
                                    } else {
                                        let myid = String(data[key]._id);
                                        Object.defineProperty(contacts, data[key].address, {
                                            value: {
                                                "000": {
                                                    "body": data[key].body,
                                                    "date": date
                                                }
                                            }
                                        });
                                    }
                                }
                            }
            return contacts;
        }
    );
}
```

EDIT 2 : I call my function like that, but my for in loop is still not executed , although my variable seems correctly loaded.

```
    sms.getAllSMS().then( allSMS => {
        console.log('allSMS');
        console.log(allSMS);
        console.log('then is readed'); // this is readed
        for (let key in allSMS) {
            console.log(allSMS[key]); // this is not executed
        }
    }).catch(
        error => console.warn("something is wrong")
    );
```

Here's a screenshot of the console ('Object' in the console is allSMS). Next to "Object" there's a little "i" that says : "Value below was just evaluated right now". 
[image: console]
[image]

Comment: You need to show us the code inside the `getAllSMS`. Something in there is taking the time, and it is what needs to be wrapped in a promise. If the `let allSMS = sms.getAllSMS();` you have does not work, putting some promises around the call will not change anything about the function not working.

Comment: See the [mdn doc for `then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then), it has 2 parameters. Look also at `Promise.prototype.catch()`.

`resolve()` generally doesn't take a function as a parameter, the code you have there you probably want to put in `then()`. Just look at some examples.

Comment: return new promise in function sms.getAllSMS() and write function getAllSMS in then()

Comment: Updated answer, your getAllSMS is returning an object that may or may not be mutated into something valuable in the future. Instead you should return a promise so you know when the data is available and if it is available (no error).

Comment: @Bergi yes, I misunderstood how to use the promises, that's why I tried to put it "around" that function. But I know the function works because if I do a console.log of the variable `contact` supposed to be return inside the function, it's working. If I try to console.log it in the then function like that : `sms.getAllSMS().then( allSMS => { console.log(allSMS);}`, it's also working. But the for in loop after is still not executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect sms.getAllSMS returns a promise so you can try the following:

```
sms.getAllSMS()
.then(
  allSMS => {
    for (let key in allSMS) {
      console.log(allSMS[key]);
    }
  }
)
.catch(
  error=>console.warn("something went wrong, error is:",error)
)
```

Your getAllSMS does not return anything, make sure it returns a promise:

```
public getAllSMS(): object {
  return new Promise(//return a promise
    (resolve,reject)=>{
      if (SMS) {
        SMS.listSMS(this.filters, function (data) {
          resolve(data);//added this, resolve promise

        }, function (err) {
          console.log('error list sms: ' + err);
          reject(err);//added this reject promise
        });
      }else{
        resolve([]);//added this, resolving to empty array?
      }
    }
  ).then(
    data=>{
      let contacts = {};
      data.forEach(
        item=>{
          if ((item.address).length > 7 && (item.address).match("[0-9]+")) {
            let date = SMSManager.convertUnixDate(item.date); // on converti le format de date de listSMS
            if (contacts.hasOwnProperty(item.address)) {
              Object.defineProperty(contacts[item.address], item._id, {
                value: {
                  "body": item.body,
                  "date": date
                }
              });
            } else {
              Object.defineProperty(contacts, item.address, {
                value: {
                  "000": {
                    "body": item.body,
                    "date": date
                  }
                }
              });
            }
          };        
        }
      );
      return contacts;
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But it's still not working... I have edited my post.

Comment: @neiya Your update shows a `getAllSMS` that doesn't return anything, the `getAllSMS` in my answer returns a promise. Also `dosnt work` is not very helpful, using `sms.getAllSMS().then(...` with the `sms.getAllSMS` in your question should get a `sms.getAllSMS is not a function` error.

Comment: In my update getAllSMS() is returning a promise no ? I put a `return new Promise` at the begining of the function as you adviced me to do. I don't have any error in the console, the code in the for in loop is just not executed because I think the object is not loaded at that moment. I think there's still an error in my code but I don't find where. I added some screenshots to my post to show you the console.

Comment: @neiya Yes, I see the update now. It seems you want to resolve contacts but are mutating it asynchronously. I've updated my answer to first get the data and then mutate contacts according to the data.

Comment: I tried your code and modified it a little bit (I update it in the main post) because I can't do `forEach` on an object. But when I do `sms.getAllSMS().then()` with the for in loop inside the object is still not loaded. I want to do several different things on that object other that the for in loop, that's why don't want to put that code inside the `getAllSMS` function.

Answer (score 1):

You fixed the asynchrony problem now by using promises, that looks fine.

The problem with the `for` loop not enumerating your properties is that [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) does (by default) create non-enumerable properties. Use a simple assignment instead:

```
let contacts = {};
for (const key in data) {
    const address = data[key].address;
    if (address.length > 7 && address.match("[0-9]+")) {
        const date = SMSManager.convertUnixDate(data[key].date); // on converti le format de date de listSMS
        const myid = String(data[key]._id);
        if (address in contacts) {
            contacts[address][myid] = {
                "body": data[key].body,
                "date": date
            };
        } else {
            contacts[address] = {
               "000": {
                   "body": data[key].body,
                   "date": date
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
return contacts;
```

Comment: Oh I see, I would have never figured this out. Thanks, the for in loop works fine now.